# Conditional Formatting condition is not working using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In the code *Drop* will create dropdownlist while *Dropfill* is conditional formatting condition.The condition is if Dropdown value is "YES" then dropfill cell infill must be colored.But the infill is not being colored while running my code.To be precise i think this part of code is somewhere wrong `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _"=Drop=""YES"""`

```
For i = 1 To 2
                Drop.Select
                With Selection
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
                With Selection.Validation
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                         Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:="YES,NO"
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputMessage = "HELLO"
                    .ShowInput = True
                End With
        Dropfill.Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
                                  Formula1:= "=Drop=""YES"""
            .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
                .TintAndShade = 0.8
            End With
            Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
        Set Drop = cel0.Offset(1, 0)
        Set Dropfill = Drop.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
```

Comment: Is `Drop` a named range on the worksheet?

Comment: Yes Sir, it is named as range on worksheet.

Comment: `Dim Drop As Range, Dropfill As Range` `Set Drop = cel.Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: .... no, it has to be a named range... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64... not just a `Range` object in code, but an actual named range.

Comment: Try something like `...Formula1:=  "=" & Drop.Address() & "=""YES"""`

Comment: Its working @TimWilliams..Thanks!!